# WPF Routed Commands and ShowDialog Windows

Tags: wpf, command, showdialog, routed

I was wondering how a window opened through ShowDialog is treated in the Visual Tree.

For example, Window A opens Window B through a ShowDialog.  When firing a routed command on Window B, Window A does not receieve the command (even though it is listening for it).

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 5):

We run into this situation all the time in our application.  We use the Window.Owner property and ICommandSource.CommandTarget property for this.

For example, in Window A:

```
DialogWindow windowB = new DialogWindow();
windowB.Owner = this;
windowB.ShowDialog();
```

Then, in DialogWindow, all the controls that execute commands have their CommandTarget bound to the parent Window's Owner:

```
<Window x:Class="DialogWindow" x:Name="wnd">
    <Button Command="SomeCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding Owner, ElementName=wnd}"/>
</Window>
```

Or alternatively, if you're executing from code inside Window B:

```
SomeCommand.Execute(params, this.Owner);
```

CommandTarget will let Window A listen for CanExecute and Execute.